# Challenge. Split database 500 records in two smaller datasets, randomly

Tags: mysql

I have a database with 500 records. I want to split these records to 75% and 25% *randomly*in order to use the different datasets for training and testing to machine learning algorithms. Does anyone knows how to do that using an sql query? 
ps. I use mysql.

In addition I find this ...
select ...
from ...
where ...
ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 150 but this gives me only the first dataset

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Easiest solution would be to store the datasets into tables.
After you use your query to get the first dataset:

```
 INSERT INTO dataset1 SELECT * FROM foo ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 125
```

then do:

```
 INSERT INTO dataset2 SELECT foo.* FROM foo 
   LEFT JOIN dataset1 d1 ON foo.key=d1.key WHERE d1.key IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can I also do this, but instead of creating new tables, to store the results of each dataset to a variable? (It is because I will do this at many different datasets, and I prefer not to create 2 tables for each of these datasets). Thanks a lot for your time, and info.

Comment: @Andreas, you can use tables and store only the IDs, not all the data.

Answer (score 2):

Your queries are going somewhere.  Therefore you can get all the data in one go and tag them differently, e.g. ([SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e49cf/9/0))

```
select if(rownum>=@rn*0.75,1,2) part, q3.*
from (
  select @rn:=@rn+1 rownum, q2.*
  from (select @rn:=0) q1,
       (select * from random500 order by rand()) q2
) q3
order by part, something;
```

If the data never leaves the server, you can create a temporary table with the additional `part` column, e.g.

```
create temporary table tmp as
select if(rownum>=@rn*0.75,1,2) part, q3.*
from (
  select @rn:=@rn+1 rownum, q2.*
  from (select @rn:=0) q1,
       (select * from random500 order by rand()) q2
) q3
order by part, something;
```

And use it within the same session, e.g. `select ... from tmp where part = 1`

Otherwise, you can create it as a normal table and dispose of it later.